# Full page reload of a Facebook app with IE, but not with Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-iframe

I've developed a Facebook application using the Facebook C# SDK. Interestingly, whenever the user clicks on a link in Internet Explorer, the whole page reloads - including the friends list on the right and the chat list. If one does the same with Chrome, this doesn't happen - only the canvas page gets reloaded, but the lists on the right remain untouched.

I traced the problem using the Fiddler Web Debugger and found the following. Assume my application is called my_app, and it is deployed on Windows Azure (cloudapp.net). Thus, a click on a link (to the same page, for instance) in IE results in the following calls:

1. my_app.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx
2. www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/...
3. www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions/...
4. cloudapp/facebookredirect.axd?state=...
5. apps.facebook.com/my_app/...
6. my_app.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx

The backtrace from Chrome is completely different:

1. my_app.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx
2. www.facebook.com/extern/login_status.php?...

For some reason the authorization process from Chrome is different. I implement the authorization as it is done in the sample files from the Facebook C# SDK - using CanvasAuthorizer.Authorize(). Any ideas why this problem occurs and do you have any recommendations on how to get the Chrome behavior on IE?

Many Thanks,
Yordan

Comment: I am having the same problem. On localhost only the canvas url reloads in both IE and Chrome (for chrome I get a whole page reload if I dont use the Javascript SDK). However, when deployed on the cloud I have the whole page reload in IE but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet it's a cookie issue. IE can act odd with cookies in iFrames (which is likely why its reauthenticating with every request).

I don't know about that SDK, but try adding something like this to your code behind master page - this is a P3P privacy policy that might help.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```